# Cambiar background y color de fuente de GridView (App Windows 10)

Tags: c#, gridview, uwp

Tengo un GridView con varios numeros y tengo un evento de click en los items de este GridView.
Me gustaria de que los items que ya fueron clicados cambie las colores de el fondo y de el texto, para señalar para el usuario que ya pusieron click en ellos.

El evento es este:

```
private void dataGridNumbers_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string selectedNumber = dataGridNumbers.SelectedItem.ToString();

    if (selectedNumber == resposta)
    {
        txtBoxInfo.Text = "Congratulations! You Find the Ramdon Number!";
    }
    if (selectedNumber != resposta)
    {
        numbersCloser(Int32.Parse(selectedNumber));
    }
}
```

Comment: La verdad tengo poco conocimiento de GridView, no se cual metodos se usa para hacer el cambio de color en el item que el usuario pone el click.

Comment: Es posible también inhabilitar el ítem para no poder hacer mas click en este ítem?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear una propiedad a los elementos del listado, EnlaceVisitado y cambiar a true cuando tu decidas y con un Converter, modificar su color.

Comment: Puedes poner un ejemplo de código? solamente de como se hace el cambio de color o background?
Se puede inhabilitar el ítem para no poder hacer click en el otra ves?